# Jndi/socket connection in a bean

Tags: java, jsp, sockets, session, web

In my jsps I am using session beans. Some of the beans have JNDI(LDAP) or socket as memeber variable. So when the bean is initialized this connections are also opened.

My problem is , when I log out, these sockets or JNDI connections do not go. They remain in the memory, and which are consuming the file descriptors assigned for a tomcat.

Why these connections are not closed by finalizer()?

Is there anything to clean up all the connections after session expires? (Apart from session listener, for which I would need to change a lot of code?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use finalizers at all for one. They should be run when an object is garbage collected, but you can't know when your EJBs are GC'd **or even if they are**.

So the answer here is "don't leave connections open", which applies to sockets, JNDI, database and so many other resources.